# Run <docker> command in Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Now I have a spring boot application that is packaged as jar file. In my application, I have some operations that use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker xxx")` to interact with the docker in the local shell.

If I want to change the package method that switches the jar file to docker image and run it as a docker container, I think `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker xxx")` would become useless. Therefore, how to change my code? Use `docker-java`? or any method for the docker container to interact with the outside docker?

Comment: Do you _need_ to do this?  Remember that you can pretty easily use `docker run` or equivalents to root the entire host.  Definitely use `docker-java` over trying to run `docker` subcommands, but be really really careful about basic security concerns, and consider whether tools like job queues can meet your higher-level needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Docker socket binding, i.e. you could bind-mount `/var/run/docker.sock` into your container running the Spring Boot app. You'd also have to install Docker CLI into it.